# OpenVPN client unable to connect, previously working

Tags: openvpn

openVPN server is Ubuntu Server 18.04

Client is windoz 10

openVPN version 2.4.4

This VPN link has been working for some time. Most recently working about 2 weeks back. Since them the server has had a network reconfiguration, removing 4 VLANS from the firewall. None of which "should" have effected the VPS.

I also upgraded Ubuntu with the latest patch set and rebooted the server. The kernel was NOT upgraded (ran out of room in /boot). I have cleaned up old kernel versions, but have not done a kernel update yet. System had been up for 339 days.

Client has not been able to access the VPN since these actions took place.

**Server config**

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun

ca 2.0/keys/ca.crt
cert 2.0/keys/fw1.crt
key 2.0/keys/fw1.key  # This file should be kept secret

dh 2.0/keys/dh2048.pem

tls-auth 2.0/keys/ta.key 0

server 192.168.99.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist /var/log/openvpn/ipp.txt

push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"

client-to-client

###route-gateway 192.168.99.1 255.255.255.0
push "route 192.168.0.0 255.255.0.0"
route 192.168.99.0 255.255.255.0

topology subnet

push "dhcp-option DNS <routable address>"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
push "dhcp-option DNS <routable address>"

client-config-dir ccd

keepalive 15 240

cipher BF-CBC        # Blowfish (default)

comp-lzo
max-clients 10

###user nobody
###group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun

status openvpn-status.log
log-append /var/log/openvpn.log

verb 4      # [0-11]
mute 5
```

Client Configuration (This has not changed and was working prior to server update)

```
client 
proto udp 
dev tun 

remote <routable IP of VPN server> 1194 

nobind 

ca ca.crt 
cert boson.crt 
key boson.key 

ns-cert-type server 
tls-auth ta.key 1 

cipher BF-CBC 
comp-lzo 

user nobody 
group nogroup 
persist-key 
persist-tun 

mute-replay-warnings 

verb 3 
mute 5
```

**Log file entries when starting openVPN**

```
Fri Jun 12 16:52:37 2020 us=833783 Current Parameter Settings:
Fri Jun 12 16:52:37 2020 us=833922   config = '/etc/openvpn/fw1.conf'
Fri Jun 12 16:52:37 2020 us=833993   mode = 1
Fri Jun 12 16:52:37 2020 us=834025   persist_config = DISABLED
Fri Jun 12 16:52:37 2020 us=834054   persist_mode = 1
Fri Jun 12 16:52:37 2020 us=834082 NOTE: --mute triggered...
Fri Jun 12 16:52:37 2020 us=834137 286 variation(s) on previous 5 message(s) suppressed by --mute
Fri Jun 12 16:52:37 2020 us=834171 OpenVPN 2.4.4 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on May 14 2019
Fri Jun 12 16:52:37 2020 us=834211 library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018, LZO 2.08
Fri Jun 12 16:52:37 2020 us=835577 Diffie-Hellman initialized with 2048 bit key
Fri Jun 12 16:52:37 2020 us=836723 Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Fri Jun 12 16:52:37 2020 us=836774 Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Fri Jun 12 16:52:37 2020 us=836848 TLS-Auth MTU parms [ L:1622 D:1184 EF:66 EB:0 ET:0 EL:3 ]
Fri Jun 12 16:52:37 2020 us=837324 ROUTE_GATEWAY <routable address>/255.255.255.240 IFACE=eth1 HWADDR=00:14:c2:c2:4d:44
Fri Jun 12 16:52:37 2020 us=837850 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Fri Jun 12 16:52:37 2020 us=837963 TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
Fri Jun 12 16:52:37 2020 us=838034 do_ifconfig, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Fri Jun 12 16:52:37 2020 us=838103 /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
Fri Jun 12 16:52:37 2020 us=846557 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 192.168.99.1/24 broadcast 192.168.99.255
Fri Jun 12 16:52:37 2020 us=857371 /sbin/ip route add 192.168.99.0/24 via 192.168.99.2
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Fri Jun 12 16:52:37 2020 us=863665 **ERROR: Linux route add command failed: external program exited with error status: 2**
Fri Jun 12 16:52:37 2020 us=863798 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1622 D:1450 EF:122 EB:406 ET:0 EL:3 ]
Fri Jun 12 16:52:37 2020 us=863844 Could not determine IPv4/IPv6 protocol. Using AF_INET
Fri Jun 12 16:52:37 2020 us=863906 Socket Buffers: R=[212992->212992] S=[212992->212992]
Fri Jun 12 16:52:37 2020 us=863968 UDPv4 link local (bound): [AF_INET][undef]:1194
Fri Jun 12 16:52:37 2020 us=864012 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_UNSPEC]
Fri Jun 12 16:52:37 2020 us=864064 MULTI: multi_init called, r=256 v=256
Fri Jun 12 16:52:37 2020 us=864157 IFCONFIG POOL: base=192.168.99.2 size=252, ipv6=0
Fri Jun 12 16:52:37 2020 us=864223 IFCONFIG POOL LIST
Fri Jun 12 16:52:37 2020 us=864382 Initialization Sequence Completed
Fri Jun 12 17:16:13 2020 us=113751 TLS Error: cannot locate HMAC in incoming packet from [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:37399
Fri Jun 12 17:16:14 2020 us=125964 TLS Error: cannot locate HMAC in incoming packet from [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:37400
Fri Jun 12 17:17:19 2020 us=309702 TLS Error: cannot locate HMAC in incoming packet from [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:57783
Fri Jun 12 17:17:20 2020 us=310465 TLS Error: cannot locate HMAC in incoming packet from [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:57784
```

**Port listening**

```
> netstat -apn |grep -w 1194
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1194            0.0.0.0:*                           7379/openvpn
```

Comment: This is probably due to a mismatch in tls-auth configuration. The client needs to have the same TLS key available and should have something like `tls-auth path/to/ta.key 1`. You should post your client configuration so that it can be compared to the server side.

Comment: James thanks for looking at this. I have added the client config file to the question. The client config has not changed and was working last week prior to the server updates I made. Both software updates and removing 4 VLANs. The VPN server is also the firewall running on Ubuntu 18.04.  I wanted to add a bounty on this question as it is becoming a critical issue.

Comment: I was able to monitor the VPN server while the client attempted access. tcpdump did not show any traffic on port 1194, and no entries were seen in the firewall log. The client was unable to ping the VPN servers routable IP, so traceroute did not show anything as well. It is probably that the WiFi access point that was being used (public library) had disabled ICMP.

Comment: Two days later the client was able to connect successfully while using WiFi at a fast food outlet. The only thing I can surmise is that the library was disabling most ports outbound except those used for email and web traffic. I would like to do the same monitoring during a successful VPN connection to see what that behavior looks like.

Comment: Since the VPN has continued to work correctly with no changes to my configuration I have to assume that the failure was caused by something outside my LAN. Perhaps DNS, routing, etc. I will close this question. James, thanks for taking a look at this.